# Centralize text label regardless of length?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Is there a way of centralizing a text label so that it's always bang in the center regardless of text length? The text label shows people's names from their Facebook profiles but shorter names make the text look off-center. Example of what I want to centralize:

```
public var nameFormat = new TextFormat("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 28, 0xFFFFFF, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

var PHPvariablespassedin:Object = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
nameText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
nameText.text = String(PHPvariablespassedin['username']);
interfaceLayer.addChild(nameText);
nameText.x = 186;
nameText.y = 80;
nameText.width = 750;
nameText.wordWrap = true;
nameText.selectable = false;
nameText.embedFonts = true;
nameText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
nameText.setTextFormat(nameFormat);
```

Thank you.

Comment: do you mean a TextField or a TextLabel(of a buton or something)?! As always some code would help to help!

Comment: ok, like fsbmain said. use TextFormat.TextFormatAlign.CENTER

Comment: Hmm, it's not working for `nameText` but working for others. Perhaps something to do with the fact that `nameText.text` is the user's name pulled from their Facebook profile rather than a set number / characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution, I think it's the most suitable in your case (center text via `TextFormat.align` property for fixed width*height of text field):

```
    var tf:TextField = new TextField();
    //this is by default is NONE, but we must be sure
    tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.NONE;

    //the main idea set align property to TextFormatAlign.CENTER
    var format:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Arial", 12, 0x000000, null, null, null, null, null, TextFormatAlign.CENTER);

    //set size to fit the format size (this may be already done in flash IDE for example in your skin)
    tf.height = 22;
    tf.width = 100;
    tf.defaultTextFormat = format;
    tf.text = "small";
```

Comment: I don't think TextFieldAutoSize.NONE will allow the TextFied to grow to show all of the content.

Comment: but with autoSized text field center with TextFormat align won't work. It's seems topic author have static skin, so I guess he has fixed area for text field, so he has non autosized text field, His code also confirm this my suggestion )

Comment: Do I need to remove my x and y positioning for this to work? I tried just adding `TextFormatAlign.CENTER` without changing anything else and it didn't work. Do I need to change the width of the text field or anything?

Comment: Well, honestly, if that is what he wants he shoud just put a TextField on the stage and make it the width of the area and click the center align button.

Comment: My text fields are dynamically added to the stage using Actionscript.

Comment: Yes, unfortunatey too many people don't know how to use the timeline/stage properly, so they wind up trying to code things that are really simple to do without code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a background object (which can be transparent) that is the size that you want your TextField to be centered within. Let's assume these things:

- Your MC has a registration point at the top left
- The background object is positioned at 0, 0
- You have a TextField on the stage with an instance name of `textField`

You can then apply this as the Base Class of the MovieClip

```
public class CenteredTextt extends Sprite {

   public var textField:TextField;//will be populated by Flash from the stage
   protected var _text:String;

   public function get text():String {
      return _text;
   }
   public function set text(value:String):void {
      if (textField) {
          textField.defaultFormat = textField.getTextFormat();//may want to move this to a constructor, since it only needs to be done once
          textField.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
          textField.htmlText = text;
          textField.x = width/2 - textField.width/2;
          textField.y = height/2 - textField.height/2;
      }
   }
}
```